# How to make trigger on view to insert old and new both value in other table

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
I want to insert that records in table 'STATUS_CHANGE'(this is blank table)
 and table structure given below.

      CREATE TABLE "STATUS_CHANGE" 
       (
        APPLICANT_ID NUMBER, 
        PARTNER_ID NUMBER, 
        OLD_APP_STATUS_ID NUMBER(3,0),
        NEW_APP_STATUS_ID NUMBER(3,0),
        MODIFIED_ON DATE
       ) ;


Using trigger code is given below .

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRI_STATUS_CHANGE
INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON STATUS_ID_VEW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO STATUS_CHANGE(APPLICANT_ID, PARTNER_ID,OLD_APP_STATUS_ID,NEW_APP_STATUS_ID,MODIFIED_ON)
VALUES (:old.APPLICANT_ID,:old.PARTNER_ID, :old.APPLICANT_STATUS_ID, :new.APPLICANT_STATUS_ID, datetime('now'));
END;
/
```

> Note:- My requirement is, I have created a view "STATUS_ID_VEW" of
>   table APPLICANT,Soi want that when if any changes happen on table
>   APPLICANTS on column 'APPLICANT_STATUS_ID' then record insert into
>   "STATUS_CHANGE" table with  old and new APPLICANT_STATUS_ID with
>   system date, I have triedthis way but nothing happen please suggest.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: "nothng happen" - when you create the trigger, or when you insert/update? Was the trigger created, and is it valid? Is `datetime()` your own function, that you are using instead of `sysdate` for some reason?

Comment: Thank you Alex,  yes trigger created successfully but when i am updating table then trigger is not fire means no  value inserted by the trigger in table 'STATUS_CHANGE'. Please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

1. Datetime() is not an oracle function. Use sysdate instead. I think you missed the compilation error and the trigger is not compiled.

   Error(2,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

   Error(3,96): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DATETIME": invalid identifier

   SELECT STATUS FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'TRI_STATUS_CHANGE';
2. You use an INSTEAD OF trigger. This means the trigger code is executed instead of the actual insert or update on the VIEW (underlying TABLE). So you can only expect changes in the STATUS_CHANGE table not in the APPLICANT table.
3. Why is the trigger on the view? This means that changes directly on the APPLICANT table do not result in execution of the trigger code. So no changes on the STATUS_CHANGE table.

Execute:

```
CREATE TABLE "STATUS_CHANGE" 
       (
        APPLICANT_ID NUMBER, 
        PARTNER_ID NUMBER, 
        OLD_APP_STATUS_ID NUMBER(3,0),
        NEW_APP_STATUS_ID NUMBER(3,0),
        MODIFIED_ON DATE
       ) ;

CREATE TABLE APPLICANT (    
 APPLICANT_ID NUMBER
,PARTNER_ID NUMBER
,APPLICANT_STATUS_ID NUMBER(3,0));

CREATE VIEW STATUS_ID_VEW 
AS 
SELECT APPLICANT_ID,PARTNER_ID,APPLICANT_STATUS_ID FROM APPLICANT;



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRI_STATUS_CHANGE
INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON STATUS_ID_VEW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO STATUS_CHANGE(APPLICANT_ID, PARTNER_ID,OLD_APP_STATUS_ID,NEW_APP_STATUS_ID,MODIFIED_ON)
VALUES (:new.APPLICANT_ID,:old.PARTNER_ID, :new.APPLICANT_STATUS_ID, :old.APPLICANT_STATUS_ID, sysdate);
END;
/

insert into STATUS_ID_VEW values (1,1,1);
insert into APPLICANT values (2,2,2);

select * from STATUS_CHANGE;
select * from APPLICANT;
```

Output:

```
APPLICANT_ID PARTNER_ID OLD_APP_STATUS_ID NEW_APP_STATUS_ID MODIFIED_ON        
------------ ---------- ----------------- ----------------- --------------------
           1                                              1 27-MAY-2015 13:32:09 

APPLICANT_ID PARTNER_ID APPLICANT_STATUS_ID
------------ ---------- -------------------
           2          2                   2
```

Insert into STATUS_ID_VEW only executes the trigger and result only in a record in the STATUS_CHANGE table (first output record)

Insert into APPLICANT bypasses the trigger and result only in a record in the APPLICANT table (second output record)

**EDIT**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRI_STATUS_CHANGE
AFTER UPDATE OF APPLICANT_STATUS_ID ON APPLICANT 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO STATUS_CHANGE(APPLICANT_ID, PARTNER_ID,OLD_APP_STATUS_ID,NEW_APP_STATUS_ID,MODIFIED_ON)
  VALUES (:new.APPLICANT_ID,:old.PARTNER_ID, :new.APPLICANT_STATUS_ID, :old.APPLICANT_STATUS_ID, sysdate);
END;
/
```

Comment: @
Robert Merkwürdigeliebe thank you very much, but i need  to insert  data table in STATUS_CHANGE with new  and old value, when update  on field of APPLICANT_STATUS_ID  in APPLICANT table . APPLICANT is existing table  it have records in lakes

Comment: @AnandYadav And your question is? I've updated the answer with what I think you ask for. If this is still not what you need : be more specific in your functional requirements and show us what you got so far